# Proving multiple union proposition in A first Course in Probability

Tags: probability

The proposition that I am talking about appears in the page 31, Chapter 2, of A first course in Probability, by Sheldon Ross. The proposition is the following:

> $ P(E1 \cup E2∪...∪En) = \sum_{i=1}P(E_i) - \sum_{i_1<i_2} P(E_{i_1}E_{i_2}) + ... + (-1)^{r+1} \sum_{i_1<i_2<...<i_r} P(E_{i_1}E_{i_2}...E_{i_r}) + ... + (-1)^{n+1} P(E_{i_1}E_{i_2}...E_{i_n})$

I really cannot understand the demonstration that comes in the book, specially the part in which it mentions for the first time the changing sign of each of the addends (that comes from a sum and difference of combination notes).

Comment: The union of $E_1$ and $E_2$ is $P(E_1\cup E_2)=P(E_1)+P(E_2)-P(E_1,E_2)$. Do you see where the minus sign comes from?

Comment: The short notation of the whole formula is $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i)=\sum_{r=1}^n (-1)^{r-1}\cdot \sum\limits_{1\leq  i_1< i_2<....< i_r\leq n} P(\bigcap_{j=1}^r E_{i_j})\quad r=1,2,...,n$

Comment: @callculus42 I prefer using indexing set notation,  $\Pr\left(\bigcup \limits_{i=1}^n A_i\right) = \sum\limits_{r=1}^n(-1)^{r-1}\sum\limits_{\Delta\in \binom{[n]}{r}}\Pr\left(\bigcap\limits_{i\in \Delta} A_i\right)$

Comment: @JMoravitz It is maybe too mysterious for some people. Nevertheless the OP can leave a comment. But I think he/she will not.

Comment: @callculus42 I see where the initial minus is coming from, but I don't see where the further additions and minus come from. Also, there are multiple reasons why someone wouldn't answer immediately, chill out.

Comment: @pdaranda661 I cannot post a detailed answer here. Maybe you can repost your question. Btw, you can accept answers to your previous questions.